# Response time is delayed when we have multiple requests in oodo server or openerp?

Tags: python, python-2.7, odoo, openerp-8

My Openerp version is 8.0.

I am very new to the openerp module.My problem is that if i hit the server with the multiple requests I am getting the response after completion of the all the requests processing, to all the requests. What I want from this scenario is, whenever the single request process done among multiple requests that should be served with the relevant response. But I am not getting here. Please suggest me some Ideas.I tried to find out the solution, but I am not able to get that.Thanks in advance.

Comment: How are you making these requests? Can you post the relevant code pieces here?

Comment: Hey @mu I am requesting the servers using the rest clients.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Odoo server can process only one request at a time.
This means that other request have to wait until they are processed.

The solution is to run Odoo in [multiprocess mode](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/setup/deploy.html#builtin-server), where several workers can handle requests is parallel ([docs](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/reference/cmdline.html#cmdoption-odoo.py--workers)):

Use the `--workers=x` option, where `x` is the number of workers to spawn.

The recommended number of workers to use is `2*n+1`, where `n` is the number of processors of the server.

Workers also provide better memory management, since they regularly restarted. They are recycled when reaching one of the thresholds, such as a max number of requests `--limit-request` (defaults to 8196) or memory usage `--limit-memory-soft` (defaults to 640Mb).

Comment: Thanks Daniel for the quick response. But one thing bothered me that, how many workers I need to take to run the application. Because suppose if I taken 2 workers the processing time is by default limit_CPU = 60 seconds, limit_real = 120 seconds, after completion of the limit span the workers is going to kill and my response is connection failure. Finally what I want to ask you that should I make CPU limit, real limit larger or not? And if I did that is there any impact of the CPU performance and memory storage. Please suggest me on this. Once again thanks.

Comment: I expanded the answer on the number of workers. AFAIK there is no recommendation to change those default limits. I suggest you keep them, and change them later if your users experience problems.

Comment: I found a new information from your answer like workers will restarted automatically. What my question is that when these things I mean workers are going to restart? whether if we have a limit time is larger or something else?

Comment: Just use the default until you believe they need tweaking. Workers are recycled when reaching a number of requests or memory limit. See the limit configs for details.

Comment: Will this workers going to be specific to some requests or all the requests hitting the server.